# Get activation functions (and hyperparamters) of trained model keras/tensorflow in R Studio

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a model with keras/tensorflow in R Studio and stored it.
I now reload the model with

```
 my_model <- load_model_hdf5("my_model.h5")
```

with

```
summary(my_model)
```

I get a summary of the model, including number and size of layers.
Yet, I don't see what the activation functions are.

Is there a way to the access the activation functions?

Secondly, is there also a way to access the hyperparameters as epoch number, batch size,.. that were used in training this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Netron](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/) with loading your `.h5` file. Netron is highly useful.